# Grouping events based on distance and time

Tags: r

I have a dataset with events (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, latitude, longitude) and I a want to group these events based on two criteria. If the events occurred within 20 km of each other and within 1 second after another then they are grouped together as a single event. I have tried to group the events using a series of for loop, but it takes to long because there around 1.5 mil. events. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of conducting this type of analysis. I have include a sample of the input file.

| year | month | day | hour | minute | second | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 23 | 46.2452316 | 43.35 | 26.846 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 23 | 46.5867386 | 43.24 | 26.883 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 25 | 47.2160149 | 43.281 | 26.959 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 38.0627136 | 43.346 | 27.24 |
| 10 | 1 | 5 | 23 | 32 | 37.9809761 | 43.033 | 19.12 |
| 10 | 1 | 5 | 23 | 32 | 37.9879913 | 43.045 | 18.998 |
| 10 | 1 | 5 | 23 | 39 | 35.3192711 | 42.943 | 18.934 |
| 10 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 57.6164627 | 42.979 | 19.291 |
| 10 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 11 | 7.6762986 | 42.928 | 19.431 |
| 10 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 18 | 32.5538177 | 42.883 | 19.734 |
| 10 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 28 | 7.1016998 | 42.95 | 19.634 |

Comment: Make a date-time variable from `c(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)`, then use cut() on the time. It won't actually group on one-second and 20 km proximity but calculating that would be time prohibitive with the size of your data. You would instead get "cells" on a time/space grid and could count items within those cells.

Comment: After thinking more on this question, I have finally produced a working and valid solution and have updated my answer accordingly. Apologies for any inconvenience this may have caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the second version of this answer as issues were found with the original. I have validated this approach and it works now. As with the original, this may or may not work in a 'realistic' timeframe for your data for reasons outlined below, but it does for the sample dataset I used. First, some notes:

1. Whether this is efficient enough depends on the range of time values and the density of points in your data.
2. This was run on a Win10 x64 CPU @ 3.20GHz 16GB RAM machine with an SSD, the quoted processing times may vary depending on your machine
3. There is *a lot of redundancy* in this approach e.g. calculations may be run on multiple points multiple times. I have heavily annotated the code so hopefully others can point out where efficiencies can be found. Further, this approach loops through each grid cell, and as such identical groups may occur in the results dataframe "disttime" e.g.:

```
grid  row col1 col2
   1    1    2    3   
   2    2    3    1
   3    3    1    2
```

and these will need to be accounted for

4. You will likely need to play around with various "cellsize" values in order to ensure the number of points in each grid cell is manageable. In the example below, `cellsize <- 15000` resulted in 1875 cells and the following points per cell stats:

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 4.0   827.5   856.0   800.0   879.0   981.0
```

This may not have been the optimal "cellsize", potentially a larger size may reduce the time required

5. The main time-intensive process is creating the distance matrices. Functions in the `sf` package such as `st_is_within_distance()` proved to be impractical, and it did not appear to be much more efficient to use *Euclidean distance* rather than *great circle distance*. Again, hopefully others may know more efficient methods
6. Creating a `difftime()` matrix is significantly faster than a distance matrix, so the time matrix is created first and used to re-subset the data. In other words, there's no point calculating distances for points if they're not within `search_time` of each other. The example below uses a search distance of <= 20km (`search_dist <- 20`) and a search time of <= 1000 seconds (`search_time <- 1000`) in order to ensure some results are returned. Depending on the range of your time values, you may not gain a huge saving from the re-subsetting process. However, a lower `search_time` than the one used in this example will definitely result in faster processing times. For instance, when I set `search_time <- 1` and no matches were found for a given grid cell, that iteration took ~3 seconds or less
7. Clusters as defined by the OP represent 'many to many' relationships, and the creation of the "disttime" file uses a 'one to many' approach. This results in 'false positives' being included as clusters, so a subsequent step is included to remove these.

With all that in mind, this is how you can hopefully process your data.

Load packages and create sample dataframe (just load packages if you want to use your own data):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
library(sf)
library(splancs) # For selecting points within buffer
options(digits.secs=3) # For seconds precision

set.seed(1) # For sample df only
rowcount <- 1.5e6 # For sample df only
search_dist <- 20 # In km
search_time <- 1000 # In seconds
# Set grid size in m for dividing data into smaller chunks
cellsize <- 15000

# Create sample dataframe
sampledf <- data.frame(year = sample(10:15, rowcount, replace = TRUE),
                       month = sample(1:12, rowcount, replace = TRUE),
                       day = NA,
                       hour = sample(0:23, rowcount, replace = TRUE),
                       minute = sample(0:59, rowcount, replace = TRUE),
                       second = runif(rowcount, min = 0, max = 59.999),
                       latitude = runif(rowcount, min = 42, max = 44),
                       longitude = runif(rowcount, min = 18, max = 28))

df <- sampledf %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  mutate(day = ifelse(month %in% c(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12),
                      sample(1:31, n(), replace = TRUE),
                      ifelse(month %in% c(4, 6, 9, 11),
                             sample(1:30, n(), replace = TRUE),
                             ifelse(month == 2 & year %in% c(2012),
                                    sample(1:29, n(), replace = TRUE),
                                    sample(1:28, n(), replace = TRUE))))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

00: Create tidy copy of your dataset with a datetime column:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(datetime = make_datetime(year = year + 2000,
                                  month = month,
                                  day = day,
                                  hour = hour,
                                  min = minute,
                                  sec = second)) %>%
  arrange(datetime) %>%
  mutate(row = 1:n()) %>% # Reference ID column
  select(latitude:row) %>%
  rename(x = "longitude", y = "latitude") # For subsetting points using inpip(), which expects x and y variables
```

01: Create grid of cells, buffered grid, and add grid cell values to df

```
# 01a. Create sf of points
sf_points <- df %>% 
  select(row, x, y) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords=c("x", "y")) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

# 01b. Create grid of cells based on sf_points
sf_grid <- sf_points %>% 
  st_transform(3857) %>% 
  st_make_grid(cellsize = cellsize, square = FALSE) %>% 
  st_transform(4326)  

# 01c. Create buffered grid
sf_buffer <- sf_grid %>%
  st_transform(3857) %>% 
  st_buffer(search_dist * 1000) %>% 
  st_transform(4326)

# 01d. Add sf_grid id to points
sf_points_grid <- sf_points %>% 
  st_join(
    sf_grid %>% st_as_sf() %>%
      rowid_to_column("grid"),
    join = st_intersects, left = FALSE)

# 01e. Add grid ids to df
df <- left_join(df, sf_points_grid, by = "row") %>% 
  select(!geometry) %>%
  arrange(grid) %>%
  group_by(grid) %>%
  mutate(grid_id = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup()

# 01f. Return vector of all grid cell values
gridIDs <- unique(df$grid)

# 01g. Create empty dataframe to hold results
disttime <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0))
```

02: Loop through df and find points within search_dist and search_time

```
ft <- Sys.time() # For print() outputs
for(i in gridIDs) {
  
  st <- Sys.time()
  # Get subset of points to analyse
  # 2a. Get coordinates of buffered cell for current gridID
  current_buff <- data.frame(st_coordinates(sf_buffer[i])) %>%
    select(x = "X", y = "Y")
  
  # 02b. Subset df based on min/max of current sf_buffer cell
  tmp <- df %>%
    filter(y > min(current_buff$y) & y < max(current_buff$y) & 
             x > min(current_buff$x) & x < max(current_buff$x))
  
  # 02c. Subset tmp based on actual current sf_buffer cell extent
  tmp <- tmp %>% 
    mutate(inbuff = 1:nrow(tmp) %in% inpip(tmp, current_buff)) %>%
    filter(inbuff == TRUE) %>%
    rowid_to_column(var = "matrix_id") %>%
    select(matrix_id, y, x, datetime, row, grid, grid_id)
  
  # 03. Create time matrix
  m1 <- abs(outer(tmp$datetime, 
                  tmp$datetime, 
                  difftime,
                  units = "secs"))
  
  # 03a. Filter pairs <= search_time apart
  m1 <- which(m1 > 0 & m1 <= search_time, arr.ind = TRUE)
  
  if(length(m1) == 0) {
    
    print(paste0("No points within search_time for grid ", i))
    print(paste0("time taken: ",
                 round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(Sys.time() - st, 
                                                    units = "secs")),2),
                 ", total time ",
                 round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(Sys.time() - ft, 
                                                    units = "secs")),2)))
    next
    
  } else {
    
    # 04. Subset tmp again based on unique m1 values
    tmp <- tmp %>% 
      filter(matrix_id %in% unique(unlist(data.frame(m1)))) %>%
      mutate(matrix_id = 1:n())
    
    # 05. Create distance matrix (choke point)
    m2 <- tmp %>% 
      select(y, x) %>%
      st_as_sf(coords = c("y", "x")) %>%
      st_set_crs(4326) %>%
      st_distance()/1000
    
    # 05a. Convert distance matrix values to numeric
    m2 <- matrix(as.numeric(m2), ncol = ncol(m2))
    
    # 06. Recreate time matrix
    m1 <- abs(outer(tmp$datetime, 
                    tmp$datetime, 
                    difftime,
                    units = "secs"))
    
    # 06a. Convert matrix values to numeric
    m1 <- matrix(as.numeric(m1), ncol = ncol(m1))
    
    # 07. Find values that are within search_dist and search_time
    m3 <- matrix((m1 > 0 & m1 <= search_time & (m2 > 0 & m2 <= search_dist)),
                 ncol = ncol(m2))
    
    if(length(which(m3 == TRUE)) == 0) {
      
      print(paste0("n points <= search_time but not <= search_distance for grid ", i))
      print(paste0("time taken: ",
                   round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(Sys.time() - st, 
                                                      units = "secs")),2),
                   ", total time ",
                   round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(Sys.time() - ft, 
                                                      units = "secs")),2)))
      next
      
    } else {
      
      # 08. Add df$row values (via tmp)
      m4 <- m3 %*% diag(tmp$row)
      m4[,1] <- tmp$row
      
      # 08a. Add df$grid values (via tmp)
      m5 <- m3 %*% diag(tmp$grid)
      m5[,1] <- tmp$grid
      
      # 08b. Filter m4 for at least 1 match and grid_origin == i
      m6 <- matrix(m4[which(rowSums(m4 == 0) != ncol(m4)-1 &
                              rowSums(m5 == i) > 0),],
                   ncol = ncol(m2))
      
      if(length(m6) == 0) {
        
        print(paste0("n points <= search_time & <= search_distance but != grid ", i))
        print(paste0("time taken: ",
                     round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(Sys.time() - st, 
                                                        units = "secs")),2),
                     ", total time ",
                     round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(Sys.time() - ft, 
                                                        units = "secs")),2)))
        next
        
      } else {
        
        # 08c. Left align all non 0 values
        m7 <- data.frame(
          do.call(rbind, 
                  lapply(1:nrow(m6),
                         function(x) t(matrix(m6[x,order(m6[x,] == 0)])) )))
        
        # 08d. Remove all NA columns (columns with all 0) and rename columns
        m8 <- m7 %>% 
          select_if(~!all(. == 0)) %>%
          rename(row = "X1")
        
        colnames(m8)[2:ncol(m8)] <- c(paste0("col", 1:(ncol(m8)-1)))
        
        # 08e. Add grid cell values (for easy viewing of groups in results)
        m8 <- m8 %>% 
          mutate(grid = i) %>%
          relocate(grid)
        
        # 09. Add result to disttime
        disttime <- 
          bind_rows(disttime, m8)
        
        print(paste0("Clusters found: ", nrow(m4), ", time taken to process grid ", i, ": ",
                     round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(Sys.time() - st, 
                                                        units = "secs")),2),
                     " | Total time: ", round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(Sys.time() - ft, 
                                                                           units = "secs")),2)))
        
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

This took 4h8m17s to run and found 216,031 unique and non-unique clusters. The values in the "row" and "col" columns reference df$row, so data can be joined back to the original data if needed:

```
head(disttime)
  grid     row    col1 col2 col3 col4
1   13  704479  704482   NA   NA   NA
2   13  713041  713043   NA   NA   NA
3   13 1156686 1156682   NA   NA   NA
4   13 1170061 1170067   NA   NA   NA
5   13 1170067 1170061   NA   NA   NA
6   13 1156682 1156686   NA   NA   NA
```

As mentioned in point 3 above, this approach produces duplicate clusters of points. To remove these:

```
# 10. Remove unordered duplicate rows
disttime1 <- disttime %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  mutate(dupes = duplicated(t(apply(.[,-1], 1, sort)))) %>%
  filter(dupes == FALSE) %>%
  select(-dupes)
```

In the above example, there were 62,993 unique clusters filtered to "disttime1".

As mentioned in point 7, 'false positive' clusters may be produced and these need to be removed. The following code identifies true and 'false positive' clusters and separates them into separate dataframes:

```
# 11. Create dataframes to store correct and incorrect clusters
disttime_keep <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0))
disttime_del <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0))

# 12. Loop through clusters to check all point within search_time 
#     and search_dist of each other 
for(k in 1:nrow(disttime1)) {
  
  if(sum(disttime1[k,] != 0) == 3) {
    
    # 12a. If only two points, copy to disttime_keep
    disttime_keep <- disttime1 %>%
      slice(k) %>%
      bind_rows(disttime_keep, .)
    
    next
    
  } else {
    
    # 12b. If cluster > 2 points, create time matrix
    m2m <- disttime1 %>%
      slice(k) %>%
      select(where(~ any(. != 0))) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = c("row", contains("col"))) %>%
      left_join(select(df, c(row, datetime, x, y)),
                by = c("value" = "row"))
    
    mtm <- abs(outer(m2m$datetime, 
                     m2m$datetime, 
                     difftime,
                     units = "secs"))
    
  }
  
  # 12c. If any relationship is > search_time, copy to disttime_del
  if(length(which(mtm > search_time)) != 0) {
    
    print(paste0(length(which(mtm > search_time)) / 2, 
                 " intersection/s outside search_time in row ", k,
                 ". Row moved to disttime_del"))
    
    disttime_del <- disttime1 %>%
      slice(k) %>%
      bind_rows(disttime_del, .)
    
    next
    
    } else {
      
      # 12d. Create distance matrix  
      mdm <- m2m %>% 
        select(y, x) %>%
        st_as_sf(coords = c("y", "x")) %>%
        st_set_crs(4326) %>%
        st_distance()/1000
      
    }
  
  # 12e. If any relationship is > search_dist, copy to disttime_del
  if(length(which(as.numeric(mdm) > search_dist)) != 0) {
    
    print(paste0(length(which(as.numeric(mdm) > search_dist)) / 2, 
                 " intersection/s outside search_dist in row ", k,
                 ". Row moved to disttime_del"))
    
    disttime_del <- disttime1 %>%
      slice(k) %>%
      bind_rows(disttime_del, .)
    
    next
    
    } else {
      
      # 12f. If cluster points all within search_time and search_dist of each 
      #      other, copy to disttime_keep
      disttime_keep <- disttime1 %>%
        slice(k) %>%
        bind_rows(disttime_keep, .)
    }
  
}
```

This resulted in 60,480 true clusters being copied to disttime_keep.

To join the x and y coordinates to "disttime1":

```
disttime_keep1 <- disttime_keep %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("col")), ~na_if(., 0)) %>%
  mutate(cluster_id = 1:n(),
         cluster_size =  rowSums(!is.na(select(., !c(grid))))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(row, contains("col")),
               values_drop_na = TRUE,
               values_to = "row") %>%
  select(!name) %>%
  left_join(select(df, c(datetime, row, x, y)),
            by = "row")
```

And the result, showing clusters with > 2 points:
[image: result]

The issue with the first answer I provided was that upper triangle matrices were used to avoid as many duplicates as possible. This meant that true clusters encompassed by a 'false positive' cluster were excluded. For example, consider these clusters:

```
    grid     row    col1    col2    col3    col4
67   176 1336236 1336251 1336237 1336226 1336252
81   176 1336251 1336236 1336237       0       0
104  176 1336226 1336236 1336237       0       0
105  176 1336252 1336236 1336237       0       0
```

Cluster 67 is a false positive as 1336251 and 1336226, and 1336226 and 1336252 are not within "search_time" and "search_dist" of each other. By changing to symmetric matrices, the true clusters 81, 104, and 105 are included in the results where previously only cluster 67 would have been returned.